# How to trim a column value if it exceeds length - varchar -redshift in DDL while creating table

Tags: casting, amazon-redshift, trim, ddl

String exceeds ddl length error :

I want to create a table in redshift with ddl that specifies to trim if it exceeds more than characters mentioned. Is there a way ?

I tried insert into with ‘Cast ‘ but it doesn’t work for automation . So it has to be in ddl . Are there any ways ?

Answer (score 0):

SUBSTRING() is the way to function to shorten a string.  You could just insert the SUBSTRING from character 1 through the DDL length and this will prevent any overflow for normal ASCII characters.  It sounds like the long strings are already in the database so you don't need to address this for COPY, right?

Now if your strings are VARCHAR type and have multi-byte characters embedded then you have a slightly harder problem.  Since a multi-byte character takes up more than 1 VARCHAR DDL length "slot" you may need to reduce the string size more than the character count difference.  The string function OCTET_LENGTH() will give the VARCHAR DDL length of a string which will be more than the LENGTH() in characters of the string if the string contains multi-byte characters.  You can use this difference to trim a few extra characters off in the multi-byte case.  Something like this should work for both cases:

```
INSERT INTO <target> 
    SELECT SUBSTRING(<string-col>, 1, <ddl-length> - OCTET_LENGTH(<string-col>) + LENGTH(<string-col>) 
    FROM <source>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Bill Weiner is useful. I did similar, but since I'm generating  the SQL command within a PySpark application, I trimmed the data (also with SUBSTRING()) and applied a **percentage** to deal with special characters:

```
cmd = f"UPDATE {target} {string_col} SET {string_col} = substring({string_col}, 1, {int(0.90*ddl_length})"
```

You mentioned Redshift and automation. My team struggled with handling DDL errors automatically. We came up with a solution that involves creating a temporary table with longer VARCHAR length in the DDL, where we copy there data from S3. In this temporary table we substring the data and finally copy to the production table, and log the changes to later take action. This keeps the pipeline running.

We opted for the temporary table because we didn't want to automate a DDL change in production tables. I think it might get tricky if you have SCD tables.

If you want to have a look, I wrote a [Medium article](https://medium.com/@flpalps/dynamically-trim-incoming-data-if-it-exceeds-what-specified-in-schema-f11d562d4d87) about it.